# Thread / task wait for a button click

Tags: c#, multithreading

Well, I have this Windows Form application that contains a Task (*System.Thread.Tasks*) running in parallel with my application. This Task, in some point, will have to wait for a button click (which is in the main thread) and capture data from this button.
I have a code for that, which is surprisely working fine. But I believe this isn't the best approach, I think I should use Events for that, but being completly honest, I just started to learn about Events, so Im still kind of confused. If I'm right, please tell me what could I do to make it better.

here's an example of my code:

```
bool BooleanHelper = false;
int ButtonData;

private void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   BooleanHelper = true;
   ButtonData = 5; //example      
}

private void MyForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   Task t = Task.Run(()=>{
      while(!BooleanHelper){} //this can't be a good pratice .__.

      // now if the program reaches this line, it means that we can use the ButtonData.
   });
}
```

Comment: `this can't be a good pratice .__.` - Correct, it's not at all - unless you like melting your CPU.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to execute a task once a button is clicked?

Comment: @Enigmativity no sr. The Task will be executed no matter what. In some point it will have to wait for a button click before continue.

Comment: Then split the task into two function. First will automatically be started and when it finishes, it enabled the button. When then the button is clicked a second function will be called, that continues whatever has to be done.

Comment: @MWsan - You can use some of the threading semaphores for this - as per Keith's answer - but this stuff gets messy quickly and you can easily get hard to fix bugs. It would be better if you explained what your business requirement is and we can then help you with how to do this in a more robust manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of threading primitives, events are useful for this...

```
private static ManualResetEvent _continue;
int ButtonData;

private void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

   ButtonData = 5; //example      
   _ev.Set();
}

private void MyForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   Task t = Task.Run(()=>{
      _continue.Wait(); // there are versions with timeouts as well

      // now if the program reaches this line, it means that we can use the ButtonData.
   });
}
```

but there are other approaches I prefer, like Actor based dispatch.

Comment: _ev.Set(); what is this line for?

Comment: _Sets the state of the event to signaled, which allows one or more waiting threads to proceed._

Comment: I'd consider putting the set at the end of the click handler, so all the data is available to the worker thread. Also `ManualResetEventSlim` can be used in place of `ManualResetEvent`.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use a TaskCompletionSource to create a task where you can control when it finishes:

```
TaskCompletionSource<int> buttonTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

private void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  buttonTcs.SetResult(5);
}

private async void MyForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var buttonData = await buttonTcs.Task;

  // now if the program reaches this line, it means that we can use the ButtonData.
}
```

I don’t know if the task in your MyForm_Shown was just because of the busy wait you had used. If it did actually long-running stuff that would need to be wrapped in a Task.Run than just move the await inside your task.